# Sudden 'access denied for user @ ip (using password: YES)'

Tags: php, mysql

My database was working fine using PHP. Just, sudden I want to access one of my website only to see this error

Access denied for user 'username' @'ip' (using password: YES)

Wen I checked, nothing has changed. All codes intact. I can't access the database from the website now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it would mean that you are using the wrong password, try logging into MySQL with secure shell, type the following:

```
$  mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

It should prompt you for a password, which you will not see yourself typing. If you are able to login with the command line, come back and tell me, otherwise it is just a problem with your password being incorrect.